# Vanilla JS - reverse every sub-string in place within a string

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

How can I reverse every sub-string in place within a string? For example this is my string

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

And want to turn it into:

```
merol muspi si ylpmis ymmud txet fo eht ...
```

I tried `myString.split(' ').reverse().join(' '));` but this reverses the position of the sub-strings instead putting the first word as last etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a simple reverse:

```js
let myString = `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.`;

console.log(myString.split(' ').map(word => word.split(``).reverse().join(``)).join(` `))
```

But this approach ignores the upper case at the 1st word and the dot at the end.

if You want to correct the upper case letter and the dot you can do this:

```js
let myString = `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.`;

console.log(myString.split(' ').map(word => word.split(``).reverse().join(``)).join(` `))

console.log(myString.split(' ').map(word => {
    const firstLetterIsUppercase = word.charAt(0) === word.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    const lastCharacterIsDot = word.charAt(word.length -1 ) === `.`;
    let revertWord = word
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(``)
        .reverse()
        .join(``);
    if (firstLetterIsUppercase) {
     revertWord = revertWord.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + revertWord.slice(1); 
    }

    if (lastCharacterIsDot) {
        revertWord = revertWord.slice(1) + `.`;
    }

    return revertWord;
}).join(` `))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

You are given a string and you need to reverse every sub string in place. Assuming that these "sub strings" are separated with one space between every pair.

### Solution

The algorithm can be defined like following:

1. Split original string into sub strings.
2. Reverse each sub string
3. return string with reversed sub strings separated by one space each

Your code would look something like this

```js
let str = `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.`;

let words = str.split(' '); // get sub srings

words.map(each => each.split('').reverse().join('').toLowerCase()); // each word is now reversed

let rev_str_inplace = words.join(' ');
console.log(rev_str_inplace);
// 'merol muspi si ylpmis ymmud txet fo gnitnirp dna gnittesepyt .yrtsudni'
```

### EDIT

If you want to remove the dot in your reversal you can just modify the reversal pat of the code like this

```
words.map(each => each.split('.').map(c => c.split('').reverse().join('').toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split twice and join twice to reverse each letter. This might help.

```js
const str = Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
str.split(' ').map(i => i.split('').reverse().join('')).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverseStr(str){
  let rev=""
  for(let i=str.length;i>=0;i--){
    rev+=str.charAt(i)
  }
  
  //return rev;//to reverse a string
  return rev.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');//to reverse the string in place
}
console.log(reverseStr("hello how"))
```